# Dockerfile with net core 3.1 api not published from dockerfile

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, dockerfile, asp.net-core-3.1

Here is the problem:

I have to send a asp.net core 3.1 api to a client.
I did published it through VisualStudio as self-contained (linux-64x) in order to ship less files as it is a third-part partner.

Before sending it i'm trying to test it with docker. The client wont have access to any code repository or anything, except the package. How to make it run throug Dockerfile? I've tried several examples but none of them seems to work. I'm new to docker but what i found is that every dockerfile example does things like "dotnet build" or "dotnet publish", but the Api is already published. I just need it to run with the dockerfile.

Dockerfile im using:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime-deps:3.1.0-alpine3.10
WORKDIR /api
COPY publish/Api api
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:5000
CMD ["./api"]
```

Generated files from VS publish (except Dockerfile)

[image: Generated files from VS publish (except Dockerfile)]

*UPDATE*

Doing like this gives me "permission denied" error:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime-deps:3.1.0-alpine3.10
COPY . api
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:5000
CMD ["./api"]
```

*UPDATE 2*

Build command is:

```
docker build .
```

Folder structure:

[image]
[image]

Comment: What's the issue? FYI the filesystem within your docker image is case sensitive, so `./api` should be replaced by `./Api`

Answer (score 2):

If you publish it like:

```
dotnet publish Api/Api.csproj -c Release -o /publish
```

then try this one

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/runtime-deps:3.1.0-alpine3.10
WORKDIR /api
COPY /publish .
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:5000
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Api"]
```

Comment: if using a self-contained application, and using `runtime-deps`, he doesn't need `dotnet` as part of the entrypoint

Comment: That's correct, @ESG. However, without {dotnet} or using {CMD} instead of {ENTRYPOINT} keeps giving me errors such as "executable file not found" or "no such file or directory" .

Comment: Show us your whole folder structure

Comment: where is your csproj and how do you run publish command?

Comment: It’s a self-contained api. There is no need for dotnet build or publish

Comment: Of course, but we need to see all if you wanna help

Answer (score 0):

add

```
RUN chmod +x Api
```

after copy